# How to create a Python list with all (non-empty) values from a sheet column

Tags: python, json, smartsheet-api

There is a column populated with email addresses that I am trying to grab the values of for a script in python. I've managed to grab the sheet object. How do I go about adding the values from the column to a dictionary?

Here's an example of what I'd be kind of looking at:

```
{
    "accessLevel": "",
    "columns": [
        {
            "hidden": true,
            "name": "_Sample_text"
        }
    ],
    "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/sheets/SheetId",
    "resourceManagementEnabled": false,
    "rows": [
        {
            "cells": [
                {
                    "columnId": 112345
                },
                {
                    "columnId": 12345,
                    "displayValue": "Jimmy@yahoo.com",
                    "value": "Jimmy@yahoo.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm considering:

- Using Regex (Feel like there has to be an easier way)
- Exporting to Excel and then loading it in that way.

What I've loosely tried:

- Converting to JSON (Not serializable)
- Using sheet.get('xyz')

Comment: HI @Smartsheet_Dev23 -- if the answer below sufficiently addresses your question, can you please mark the answer as "Accepted"? Doing so will make others more likely to benefit from this info in the future. (If you need additional info, feel free to indicate so by adding a comment below the answer, and I'll try to help further.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following sample code does what you've described. That is, it:

1. Gets data for the specified sheet by using the **Get Sheet** operation.
2. Specifies the `ID` of the column that contains the data you want to collect.
3. Iterates through the rows in the sheet, and through the cells in each row, adding the value of the specified column (only if non-empty) to a Python list.

```
sheetId = 3932034054809476

# get the sheet
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheetId) 

# specify the column ID of the column you're wanting to collect values from
column_id = 5228827298293636

# initialize a list that'll hold the values I collect from the sheet column
my_list = []

# iterate through rows, and through the cells in each row,
# adding the specified column value (if non-empty) to my_list
for row in sheet.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        if cell.column_id == column_id and not cell.value is None:
            my_list.append(cell.display_value)

# print the contents of my_list
print(str(my_list))
```

For example, let's say I want to collect the (non-empty) values from the **item_color** column of this sheet:

[image: Smartsheet sample data]

If I run the code above for this sheet (setting `sheet_id` to the ID of the sheet and `column_id` to the ID of the **item_color** column), the following list is printed to the console:

`['white', 'green', 'blue', 'red']`

Notice that although the sheet contains 5 rows, the list only contains 4 rows -- because the script only adds non-empty cell values to the list (and the **item_color** cell is empty for one of the five rows).